# Java EWS API - Determine Original vs Reply vs Forwarded emails

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am working on a application which integrates with MS Exchange to recieve user requests. As part of this requirement I need to ensure that only the original email is processed by the system. If the user replies to the sent email or forwards it again to the application I need to ignore them as duplicates.

I checked the EWS API (EmailMessage) documentation and didnt see anything that will give me that information. After searching a bit I came across an MAPI property "PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED" that might have the information I am looking for but then didnt come across any sample code that explains how to use it or derive it from the EmailMessage interface.

The only other alternative I could see is leveraging the conversation id field to check if the new email recieved is part of an existing conversation. In which case consider it to be a duplicate.

If anyone has implemented something similar please let me know

Comment: I did have the same Problem and solved it successfully.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646559/how-to-notice-if-a-mail-is-a-forwarded-mail

Comment: Nice; Thanks Jurgen. I was playing around with conversation id but didnt realize the index could be of use here. Is this something that can be completely relied upon in terms of the length of the field to be strictly 22 characters for the original message?

Comment: yes, if the index has a length of 22 ist always the original message. at least my code relies on it ;)