# Exchange 2010, find out if email is meeting invite without loading attachment

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have a mail sniffer program running on an Inbox in Exchange Server 2010 that checks emails at certain intervals.  I would like to know if it somehow is possible to programmatically check with [EWS (Exchange Web Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) if an email (EmailMessage) is a meeting invite (calendar request) without loading the attachment.

I know I can check if an attachment is an `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemAttachment` and then, after loading the email check if this is an `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment`.  But this only checks if the attachment is an invite.  Theoretically someone could forward an email with amongst other thing an email invite.  Then the email is really not a meeting invite, just a forwarded email.

Can you know if an email is a meeting invite **without** loading the attachment?  Should this not be possible with EWS, is there an authorative source for this?

**Edit: Forwarded emails**

This is outside the question, but I originally asked:

> Alternatively (but not what I am hoping for), is there a way to know
>   if an email was forwarded so that I can handle them differently?

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646559/how-to-notice-if-a-mail-is-a-forwarded-mail).  But I still would like to get an answer for my question as this answer only helps creating a workaround for some cases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the [`EmailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) **Message Class** [`ItemSchema.ItemClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.itemclass%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) property to [determine what type an item is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861573.aspx). Here is a snippet to help you out...

```cs
 FindItemsResults<Item> mailItems = inbox.FindItems(new ItemView(1000) { PropertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Id, ItemSchema.HasAttachments, ItemSchema.Subject, ItemSchema.ItemClass) }); 
 foreach (EmailMessage message in messageItems)
 {    
   if (message.ItemClass == "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request")
     // we have a meeting request
 }
```

Comment: This is correct.  Thank you!  In case someone else makes the same mistake as I did during testing;  When debugging this I used an email that had a meeting request as an attachment, not a proper meeting request.  Once I got this answer I did a reality check and  immediately I could see the `IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request` value on the `ItemClass` property.